# When is the private key generated in the SSL certificate request process?

Tags: powershell, ssl, automation, webserver, ssl-certificate

I am completely new to the world of SSL and certificate registration, so please excuse my ignorance. I've recently been tasked with automating our certificate renewal and issuance process via PowerShell, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the process.

I understand that a private key is stored server-side which is used in the encryption/decryption process, but I'm not sure *when* that private key is generated. Does this occur when the CSR is generated, or is the private key only created when the certificate is received and installed from the CA?

I've done some testing wherein I created self-signed certificates and I'm able to find a private key via OpenSSL, but I'm just not sure where it came from. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It most certainly is not

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Is it not? when I export a PFX file, I'm able to see an encrypted version of the private key, which I can decrypt via openssl.

Comment: @jmknight2 a pfx file is a certificate _container_ format - it contains the certificate (including the public part of the key), _alongside_ a copy of the private key

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Ah, that makes sense. So, does that mean that the certificate must be installed before a private key is created?

Comment: No, it means that a private key must exist _before_ a certificate can exist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this occur when the CSR is generated

Yes either *when*, or *before* the CSR is generated. The key component of the CSR is the *public key* - and the public key is effectively a *subset* of the information that makes up the private key (which is why we sometimes call it a *key pair*).

So, in order for you to generate a CSR, you first need a key pair.

Worth noticing is that since the CSR and resulting Certificate only contains the *public* part of the key, it's safe to exchange over channels where privacy can't be guaranteed.

```
   Server                         CA
     |                             |
1. Create key-pair                 |
     |                             |    
2. Create CSR w/pub-key            |
     |                             |
3. Send CSR to CA ---------------->|
     |                             |
     |                  4. Vet ownership claims in CSR
     |                             |
     |                  5. Issue signed Certificate
     |                     signature must span the pub-key
     |                             |
     |<---------------- 6. Send Certificate back
     |                             |
7. Install signed cert             |
     |                             |
8. Decrypt traffic using priv key  |
     |                             |
     |                             |
```

Notice that at no point does the private key leave your server - it's not comething the CA generates for you, so it must exist prior to you generating your CSR

> I've done some testing wherein I created self-signed certificates and I'm able to find a private key via OpenSSL, but I'm just not sure where it came from.

Worth noting is that when you create a new CSR or self-signed certificate with tools like `openssl req` or the IIS Manager, the tools silently generate the key for you unless you explicitly specify one - for IIS specifically, see [this related ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/590340/does-generating-a-csr-through-iis-7-5-on-windows-server-2008-r2-always-create-a/590408#590408)

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for the detail! I didn't realize that so much happened behind the scenes when creating CSRs. This info will help a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

The abstract flow is this:

- A public/private keypair is generated.
- The public key, and other data, goes into a CertificationRequest / Certificate Signing Request.
- The CA looks at the CSR, who submitted it, and whatever else they like, and either rejects it or issues a certificate.
- The private key holder can now associate the private key with the certificate.

There are "bad" products where the CA generates the private key and sends the customer a PFX, but it isn't the secure flow (because now "too many entities" know/have-known the private key).

If you're doing a self-signed certificate, the middle two steps are usually merged into one.